# Solaris version that uses libm.so.2

Tags: version, solaris

I'm seeing a file, libm.so.2 in our SunOSsparc directory that holds a lot of .so files.  I looked around, and it looks like it's used by the Solaris build.  [libm.so.2](http://milkyway.cs.rpi.edu/milkyway/forum_thread.php?id=29) and [libm.so.2 Solaris 8](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2009-March/016833.html).  Is this used by just Solaris8?  We support Solaris 9-11.  Is it used by all Solaris versions?

Or, how can I find the version of libm.so.2 that I have?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: We need to identify licenses we're using in our code for submission/release.  I need to figure out what version of solaris uses that file, so I can identify the license.

Comment: So far I tried:
libm.so.2 --ver
libm.so.2 -ver
readelf -d libm.so.2 | grep SONAME
ident libm.so.2

But they aren't giving me a library version.

Comment: libm.so.2 is supplied under the standard Oracle Solaris license. You don't ship it, Oracle does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libm.so.2 is the [standard C99 math library provided in Solaris 10 and later releases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_lib.html).